# Is it faster to use 1 reference for table merging or a 'chain' of references?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am querying data from a process historian that was stored using OPC. The querys run very slow. What table merging method should I expect to be faster and why when I query the data?

This:

```
and a1.TS >'15-MAR-18 07:00'                                             
and a1.TS = a2.TS                                                   
and a2.TS = a3.TS
and a3.TS = a4.TS
and a4.TS = a5.TS
and a5.TS = a6.TS
and a6.TS = a7.TS 
and a7.TS = a8.TS
and a8.TS = a9.TS
and a9.TS = a10.TS
and a10.TS = a11.TS
```

or this:

```
and a1.TS >'15-MAR-18 07:00'                                             
and a1.TS = a2.TS                                                   
and a1.TS = a3.TS
and a1.TS = a4.TS
and a1.TS = a5.TS
and a1.TS = a6.TS
and a1.TS = a7.TS 
and a1.TS = a8.TS
and a1.TS = a9.TS
and a1.TS = a10.TS
and a1.TS = a11.TS
```

Comment: Well, try and see! And tell us if there's any difference.

Comment: How can I time it? (not using the stopwatch on my phone lol)

Comment: should be the same. anyway you test it using [explain plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799344/how-can-i-see-the-execution-plan) if both have the same plan then are the same for db optimizer

Comment: @VinceMiller I have never worked with Oracle before, but I found the answer to your "How can I time it" question in under 5 secs on Google.

Comment: The phone stopwatch shouldn't be that bad. Either you get similar results, or a big difference.

Comment: @dfundako fair, how did you know it was oralce btw?

Comment: @VinceMiller The tag on the post.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second is preferable.  Why?  The first imposes a particular ordering on the `join`s.  It is possible that the optimizer recognizes that the two structures are identical, but that I wouldn't assume that is true.

One of the steps in optimization is choosing the ordering of the join operations.  This can have a big impact, particularly with regards to indexes and reducing data size.

In a well-structured database, you might not see much of a difference in performance.  You can inspect the query plan to see if they are the same.  In particular, you want `TS` to be the first key in an index on all the tables.